# Get database name prefix?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Here is one way of getting a list of databases:

```
SELECT table_schema 'dattabase_name'
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

However I only need to `SELECT` a list if they contain a certain prefix. I attempted some combinations of the following without luck:

```
SUBSTR('database',0,10),
SUBSTR(mysqltable_schema 'database' FROM 0 FOR 10),
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME, SUBSTR(SCHEMA_NAME, 0, 10) from information_schema.SCHEMATA
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME, SUBSTR(SCHEMA_NAME, FROM 0 FOR 10) from information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

How can I get the `substr` prefix of a database name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String positions in MySQL start at 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), so you need to use `SUBSTR(str, 1, 10)` to get the first 10 characters. Try this query:

```
SELECT table_schema as `database`, SUBSTR(table_schema, 1, 10) AS `dbprefix`
FROM `TABLES`
WHERE SUBSTR(table_schema, 1, 10) LIKE '%form%'
GROUP BY table_schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'tr%';
+----------------+
| Database (tr%) |
+----------------+
| try            |
| try_perm       |
| tryjoin        |
+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```